# Is the matrix defined by $\bar{K}_{ij}=f(x_i)f(x_j)$ for a real valued function $f$ semi-positive-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a real valued function and define $K: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$  by $K(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$.

For any vectors $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R}^m $ we define the matrix $\bar{K}_{n\times n}$  so that $\bar{K}_{ij}=f(x_i)f(x_j)$.

Must $\bar{K}$ be semi-positive-definite?

---

First, I've tried to find a counter example with no success. Then I've tried the following:

For any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n $,

$$y^t\bar{K}y=\sum_{i \neq j}y_iy_jK(x_i)K(x_j)+\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{y_i}^2K^2(x_i)$$

But I don't see any reason for this expression to be $\geq 0$.

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, put $f \equiv 0$ to get a matrix which is not positive-definite since $\overline{K} = 0$ .

Comment: Other remark, such a matrix will always be of rank at most $1$, since all lines are colinear to $(f(x_1),...f(x_n))$. It implies that it will never be definite positive provided that $n \geq 2$.

Comment: You are missing the obvious: $y^T\bar{K}y = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i f(x_i)\right)^2 \ge 0$ It is also clear $\bar{K}$ is only positive semi-definite instead of positive definite because there are $y_i$ which make $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i f(x_i) = 0$.

Comment: @SelimGhazouani: You are right, this was a terminology confusion

Comment: @achillehui: Thanks! I feel so stupid right now :)

Comment: This happens all the time and happens to everyone. Sometimes when you are stuck in a problem, the best action is walk away and come back next morning with a new unbiased mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that $y^TKy\ge0$ reducing everything to a minimization problem. Notice that by (bi-)linearity it is enough to find the minimum on the unit sphere $\|y\|^2=1$. Using Lagrange multipliers we have the function
$$L(y,\lambda)=y^TKy-\lambda(\|y\|^2-1)=y_if(x_i)f(x_j)y_j-\lambda(y_iy_i-1)$$
where we sum over repeated indices. Differentiating with respect to $y_k$ we get
$$2f(x_k)\underbrace{f(x_i)y_i}_{=:S}-2\lambda y_k=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow y_k=\frac{f(x_k)S}{\lambda}$$
The other condition gives us
$$0=\|y\|^2-1=\frac{S^2}{\lambda^2}f(x_i)f(x_i)-1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \lambda = \pm S\sqrt{f(x_i)f(x_i)}$$
Thus we obtain
$$y_k = \pm\frac{f(x_k)}{\sqrt{f(x_i)f(x_i)}}$$
Inserting this into $y^TKy$ we get
$$\frac{f(x_i)f(x_i)f(x_j)f(x_j)}{f(x_k)f(x_k)}=f(x_i)f(x_i)\ge0$$

Comment: Thanks Daniel, we've missed a much simpler solution (see achille hui's comment)